# How to reverse the process of linear filtering algorithms provided by OpenCV?

Tags: python, filter, gaussianblur

I am currently working on a Python project designed to blur certain objects in pictures by using some filtering functions provided by OpenCV, such as linear filter cv2.blur() and cv2.GaussianBlur(). However, I was told that these kinds of processes are reversable, which means those blurred regions could be restored. For this reason, I've changed my blurring algorithm to cv2.filter2D() with randomly generated convolution kernel. My code is as follows:

```
from cv2 import cv2

kernel_size = 35
# Generate a 2D kernel filled with random float
kernel = np.random.randint(1, kernel_size ** 4 + 1, size=[kernel_size] * 2)
sum_kernel = np.sum(kernel)
normalized_kernel = kernel / sum_kernel

# Read, blur and save a picture
img = cv2.imread('./cat.jpeg')
blurred_img = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, cv2.flip(normalized_kernel, -1), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
cv2.imwrite('random_blurred.jpeg', blurred_img)
```

I compared aforementioned algorithm with cv2.blur() result, code is as follows:

```
from cv2 import cv2

kernel_size = 35
img = cv2.imread('./cat.jpeg')
blurred_img = cv2.blur(img, (kernel_size, kernel_size))
cv2.imwrite('averaging_blurred.jpeg', blurred_img)
```

Here are the results of two algorithms, which are visually identical.
[random_blurred.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6skak.jpg) [averaging_blurred.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PazCh.jpg)

I don't know if my algorithm for anti-restorage actually works? Is it possible to reverse the process if the kernel used for convolution is provided? I have tried many methods including [Gonçalo Raposo](https://medium.com/@gonced8/can-you-recover-a-blurred-image-61bbcaa969d5)'s, what I finally got were images filled with snowflakes. I failed to come up with a practical solution to restore original pictures from blurred ones with known convolution kernels.

Comment: Google Wiener filtering via FFT processing for blurring and debarring. For example see https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/d3c/tutorial_out_of_focus_deblur_filter.html and https://github.com/tvganesh/deconv

Answer (score 0):

Linear filtering can be reversed as a huge linear system, where:

- each variable is an image pixel and
- each line is related to the application of the linear filter for one particular pixel.
- image border are constant initial values

This linear system will have a huge sparse matrix that is invertible for most of the kernels, and hence, lead to a closed solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).